# Texml or equivalent required for Python3

Tags: xml, latexml

I am looking for a solution to markup latex in an XML syntax on the lines of texml, however I find that the available library does not work with Python3.

Does anyone have experience of using any converter that can transform xml to latex. It is understood that the original xml may have to be transformed using XSLT to an xml syntax which is understood by the converter.

The intention is to use such library in python3

Comment: Are you looking for a Python library, or a TeX typesetting solution?

Comment: looking for a python library as I intend to implement it with Django for webapp to generate pdf documents. However if any commandline tools (non python) are available for unix/windows then please suggest, i will give it a try using piped process calls

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether my answer suits for your requirement, anyhow please try as suggested as http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/tolatex.html#xml2latex

Comment: the article is interesting. I think that DocBook format may lend itself to easy LaTeX conversion. The link related to docbook to LaTeX is not working, but I found some sources on dblatex and I will explore it further.

Comment: @SandeepRaheja Many thanks for your reply, eager to see your further comments about dblatex